# How can I execute my command in powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to install nsclient with PowerShell. This is what I have so far:

```
msiexec /q /i "Z:\NSCP-0.5.2.35-x64.msi" INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\NSClient++" CONF_NRPE=1 CONF_CHECKS=1 CONF_NSCLIENT=1 NRPEMODE=LEGACY MONITORING_TOOL=none CONF_CAN_CHANGE=1 CONFIGURATION_TYPE="ini://C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nsclient.ini" NSCLIENT_PWD="******" ALLOWED_HOSTS="10.*.*.*"
```

Somewhere I have to place grave-accent, but I have no idea where.

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error? Does the install run at all? Does it run incorrectly? Why do you think you need a grave?

Comment: I get the msiexec prompt.

Comment: It works in dos but not in powershell

Comment: Do you mean the msiexec help pop up? That is waht you get?

Comment: Also I would suggest putting /q after /i

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
msiexec /l* log.txt /i Z:\NSCP-0.4.3.143-x64.msi INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\NSClient++" CONFIGURATION_TYPE="ini://C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nsclient.ini" CONF_CAN_CHANGE="TRUE" ALLOWED_HOSTS="10.*.*.*" NSCLIENT_PWD="" CONF_CHECKS="TRUE" CONF_NSCLIENT="TRUE" /quiet
```